# Automate generation and distribution of KPI using PDF

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need some help. I have basic understanding of Power BI desktop and a lot of TSQL.

I am tasked with emailing a 2 page PDF dashboard to all of the customers in our database. I have no problem writing views over the data to provide data for all customers. But what I need to know is how I can produce a different PDF for each one and email to each customer. I want to do this every month to hundreds of customers (retailers), so I need it to be automated.

I have created one user per customer over the database and implemented row level security as this seems to be part of the solution. My users are defined as "CREATE USER @usrname WITHOUT LOGIN", but if I have to connect with the user, then it may have to also have a login

I would appreciate anything you can tell me.

Thanks in advance
Frank

Comment: hi @Frank did you try Subscribe to emails ? you can set Monthly automated emails. or you can use Power Automate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export

Comment: Hi Umut K, No I didn't. My question was much more basic than that. Try do I need Power BI Pro to do this?

Comment: You should create different report for each customer and then use power automate to send emails automatically. I was using tokens for each customer and create only one view based on these tokens (as parameter in the report) so each customer uses their own token to see their own report, this also may help you.

Comment: Hi Umut, I could produce the customer-specific report if I could apply a parameter. Would Power Automate allow me to pass a parameter?

Comment: Hi @Frank I've never tried the Power Automate with parameters but there is an article about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/input-parameters/ I used before tokens for such case. Create" the parameters and tokens table" in the Database and use the same the report for every customer.